# When i hover button, border on box

Tags: html, css

I want border on my box, when I hover on button with class .zobacz

This is what I have tried but it does not work.

```css
.product-item ~ .zobacz:hover {
    border:5px solid #000;
}

.product-item{
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-item">
 <a href="#" class="title">Platin</a>
 <a href="#" class="title-2">78411/35/30</a>
 <a href="#" class="product-item-image"><img src="images/image-product-list.jpg"></a>
 <span class="price">Cena: </span>
 <span class="price-2">265zł</span>
 <span class="price-3">NETTO</span>
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
 <a href="#" class="zobacz">Zobacz</a>
</div>
```

Is there any way to get the desired behavior using only CSS & HTML?

Comment: You're targeting the wrong thing. ~ is a sibling selector.  You want to use > or possibly even no connector at all.  If you just use:

.product-item .zobacz{}

You should be fine.
Also remember the <a> elements, are inline elements.  Set it to display: inline-block or block for more desire behaviors as well.

Comment: As pointed out there are no parent selectors in CSS however you can mimic the desired behaviour using slightly amended markup and styles as shown in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dszLb8rz/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the border to appear on the parent element (i.e. the container box), **you can't** do this using CSS seeing as that's a parent (css doesn't have a parent).
However, if you just wanted it on the element you hover, you can do:

```
 .zobacz:hover{}
```

which will work, adding a border to this element.

```css
.zobacz:hover {
  border: 5px solid #000;
}
.product-item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-item">
  <a href="#" class="title">Platin</a>
  <a href="#" class="title-2">78411/35/30</a>
  <a href="#" class="product-item-image">
    <img src="images/image-product-list.jpg">
  </a>
  <span class="price">Cena: </span>
  <span class="price-2">265zł</span>
  <span class="price-3">NETTO</span>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <a href="#" class="zobacz">Zobacz</a>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, but I want hover on box, not on 'a'element

Comment: @jaskowice1 If you want to add a border around the box you'll have to use javascript since the box is a parent of the `a`-tag.